# Special characters in powershell breaking script?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am creating a PowerShell script, and a portion is to unlock user AD accounts.
I am wondering if my password may have some special characters even if they are encapsulated with ''.
The same process used to work with a shorter password but without new password rules, then need to be longer. From what I can find this should work.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$password = "Myreallylongpassword!@#2020" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force 
$username = "myusername-admin" | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
```

Then to actually run this I have a section of script:

```
$username = read-host "Enter username you want to unlock"
Unlock-ADaccount -identity $username -credential $cred
```

From what I know this should work unless I am missing something or someone has a better way of doing this and dealing with UAC in a Windows 10 Enviroment.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: so ... what is the error? [*grin*] please, add the entire text of the error to your Question.

Comment: As an aside: Please avoid pseudo method syntax: instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions are invoked like _shell commands_, not like _methods_. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and _whitespace_-separated arguments (`,` constructs an _array_ as a _single argument_, as needed for `-ArgumentList`).

Comment: Is `$username = "myusername-admin" | ConvertTo-SecureString` really part of your code, or is that an artifact of posting here? It would (a) fail and (b) shouldn't be used, because _usernames_ must be plain-text strings (only _passwords_ must be secure strings).

Comment: I don't get an error, it just doses not unlock the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this in place of yours:

```
    $cred = New-Object Management.Automation.PSCredential “UsernameHere”, (“PasswordHere” | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Quotes and special characters

When dealing with special characters like you are, it's best to use **single quotes** instead of **double quotes** as **double quotes** can be subject to [string expansion](http://www.powershellish.com/blog/2014-12-09-strings-expansion) which can have adverse effects.  Single quotes take only the literal characters between them.

Example:

```
$longpassword = 'this is not good'

$password = "Myreally$longpassword!@#2020"
# Myreallythis is not good!@#2020
$password = 'Myreally$longpassword!@#2020'
# Myreally$longpassword!@#2020
```

## Creating PSCredential

So for generating credentials, there's a few things to correct.

- Your username does not have to be a **SecureString**.
- Note the usage of single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
$username = 'myusername-admin'
$password = 'Myreallylongpassword!@#2020' | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password
```

Comment: I made the changed such as removing the double quotes and going to single quote. Also removed the secure string from the username. I didn't notice that so thanks. I will test this the next time I get an account that needs unlocked, and let you know.